# Django: Get relative uri from views.py

Tags: django

Here is what I have currently:

urls.py:

```
 ...
url(r'this/is/relative', 'myapp.views.callview', name='myapp_callview'),
...
```

views.py:

```
def callview(request, **kwargs):

    # I can get the complete url by doing this
    print request.build.absolute_uri() # Prints: https://domain:8080/myapp/this/is/relative

    # How do I just get: /myapp/this/is/relative or even /this/is/relative
```

I would like to extract the relative uri from the view. I could just use regex, but I think there is already something out there that would let me do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you looking to extract by getting the relative url? If there's parameters you'd like to capture in the URL structure, you could include those in the URL so that they get passed to the method.

Comment: @KevinLondon: I was just looking to get the relative url and not any parameters.

Comment: might instead use something simple in the view, like:
`print(str(request.build_absolute_uri()).split(request.META.get('HTTP_HOST'))[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you `"/myapp/this/is/relative"`:

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
relative_uri = urlresolvers.reverse("myapp_callview")
```

Link to Django docs page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/